# How to use SUMPRODUCT using months and different criterion using Excel

Tags: excel, sumifs, sumproduct

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
Name   Date       Description
HallA  8/24/19    texttexttext 
HallB  8/29/19    texttexttext 
HallC  9/1/19     texttexttext 
HallB  9/4/19     texttexttext 
HallB  9/24/19    texttexttext 
HallC  10/1/19    texttexttext
```

I would like to count how many times each Hall appears within each month.

This information should populate a table that looks like this.

```
Halls  August   September  October    .......   
HallA      1            0        0 
HallB      1            2        0
HallC      0            1        1
```

Additionally, it should be built to take more information.

I have been combining a solution to this from a number of resources, both of which are not correct.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($B$2:$B)=8)) - SUMPRODUCT(--($A:$A = "HallB")) - SUMPRODUCT(--($A:$A = "HallC")) > 0, SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($B2:$B)=8)) - SUMPRODUCT(--($A:$A = "HallB")) - SUMPRODUCT(--($A:$A = "HallC")), 0)

=SUMPRODUCT(((MONTH($B$2:$B)=8)))*($A:$A = "HallA")
```

I think I've been combining so many things to the point that I'm over complicating it...

Comment: Sorry my bad you actually do not need a helper column just put the Description in the Values field and you will still get the desired output using pivot table. Btw your SUMPRODUCT formula is only comparing the month number what if they fall in different year? Formula based solution can be a bit complicated how about consider using pivot table or power query?

Comment: 1 year long table, so data will only be for 1 year

Comment: This almost works; however I am unable to group by month @TerryW

Comment: Your dates are probably in `text` format. Try converting them into `date` format then pivot table can group the dates automatically. There are many articles online demonstrating how to convert text date into date. Let me know if you still have trouble converting them.

Comment: Just got it! Post the solution as an answer for the check! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes pivot table is a powerful tool in transforming data and here is one example:

[image: Pivot Table]

Please make sure the dates are in `Date` format but not `Text` format otherwise pivot table will not be able to group the dates.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a sum product? I added a helper column with the months.

Month column = text(b2, "mmmm") filled all the way down.

Counter table = COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7, F2, $C$2:$C$7, H$1)

[image]